# Why `create()` method of django rest framework serializer return a value?

Tags: python-2.7, django-rest-framework, serialization

I don't understand why the `create()` method in DRF serializer has to return a value. E.g.:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
profile = ProfileSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'profile')

def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
    return user
```

Would not be sufficient save User istance without returning values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns the created instance so that the created `user` can be used anywhere if need be. There are often use cases where you might need the `user` or any other generic saved instance somewhere in your code. So upon saving always, the saved instance is returned so that the programmer can use it whenever need be.

Comment: Ok thanks! It seemed strange to me that the return value was mandatory

Comment: More specifically, the object returned by `create` is then serialized as the response (with the 201 status) which is why it is required and not just optional.